How to activate the pstricks option in the overarrows package?
I'm starting to understand how this very recent package overarrows works, but I can't figure out how to activate the pstricks option. The error I get is:
! Undefined control sequence.
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.7 $\overpstarrow{0}
                     $
? 

Could anyone explain what I might be missing or what steps I should follow to correctly enable the pstricks option? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{overarrows}
\NewOverArrowCommand[pstricks]{\overpstarrow}{}
\begin{document}
$\overpstarrow{0}$
\end{document}


It works with lualatex or xelatex. It's a problem between pstricks and pdflatex. But I don't know how to use pstricks with pdflatex.

that error from pstricks usually means you are using pdflatex (which can not work)

@DavidCarlisle Ah, I have forgot it. Thank you very much to both.
